# html list item with multiple columns

Tags: html

I'm trying to pretty-up a list that consists of usernames and real names (e.g. jbloggs (Joe Bloggs). I'd like the real names to line-up in a column, but when I add `<span class="col-xs-6">` around each part (see below) the list screws-up! Anyone know how to do this?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="col-xs-6">jbloggs</span><span class="col-xs-6">- Joe Bloggs</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="col-xs-6">fjibbert</span><span class="col-xs-6">- Flipperty Jibbert</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="col-xs-6">beno</span><span class="col-xs-6">- Brian Eno</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for layout, etc.

Comment: Why not using a table?

Comment: Yes, use a table. Lists are for one dimensional data structures, tables are for two dimensional ones.

Comment: `col-xx-xx` should be nested with in `row`. Without the correct nesting you will get strange behaviour. Could you provide an image showing what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use the Bootstrap classes, the easiest way to do column lists is by applying the grid classes to the `<li>` items themselves.

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="col-xs-6"></li>
    <li class="col-xs-6"></li>
</ul>
```

- `.row` is advised on the parent `ul` to get rid of the left and right margins caused by the `col-xs-6` classes.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why you've been given a -1. I can't up-vote it though ( not enough points)

Comment: Don't worry about it, if you can mark it as accepted, if you're happy it gave you the result you wanted, then thanks very much.

Comment: Think people down vote this because it is not the best answer/way to do what you want

Comment: I don't understand how it's not, it's more along the lines of what the poster asked for/wanted than the table suggestions.

Comment: Yes maybe but someone (much better than me) told me one day than if the asker make a mistake you should correct it. For me table are hardly more suitable in its case. btw the one who downvote your post should have comment to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a table for this, something like this would do the job.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>JSmith</td>
    <td>Jill</td> 
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EJackson</td>
    <td>Eve</td> 
    <td>Jackson</td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My bad - I should've been more clear about the links in the list, so that's not quite what I was after. Thanks for posting though.

Comment: With regard to links in the list its possible to put a link in a table cell as well using the a tag: <td><a href="https://www.google.com">JSmith</a></td>